# JavaScript function not defined in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, error-handling

I'm currently debugging the next tier of my website in Firefox and found a really weird bug in my JavaScript. Is it true, in Firefox, that functions need to be defined above any lines of code referencing those functions? That seems really strange to me.

#### Here's a simplified version of what was causing bugs:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(myCallback);

function myCallback() {
    // code
}
```

It threw the following bug: `Error: myCallback is not defined`

#### And here's what i needed to do for it to work in Firefox:

```
var myCallback = function() {
    // code
}

var myClass = new MyClass(myCallback);
```

**So my question is:** Is this *normal* behavior or was something else going on? I mean, do I need to take this into consideration when coding in the future?

Comment: This does not throw an error in FF 3.6: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/CRTBK/ - are you sure you're not using `var myCallback = function() { ... }`?

Comment: Is the code you cite inside an `if` block or something?

Comment: I second Boris, I had the same issue because my function was inside an if and since it was using variables defined after I set the callback, it had to be after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must define the function before calling it when you initiate with the format:

```
myCallback = function() {
    // code
}
```

But it should be ok to define anywhere when you initiate with the format:

```
function myCallback() {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Seems like an arbitrary rule at first look, but the reasoning I expect is that functions defined in the second format are defined once, and pre-compiled at execution time, but variables with functions assigned to them could change, so must be referred to after being assigned, and potentially swapped/changed numerous times before being called

Comment: In FireFox there is an [odd behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FScope_Cheatsheet#function_oddities) that I haven't seen anywhere else: