# JavaScript function works in Safari but is not found in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have very simple html and js files - which I've included below.

What is interesting (and frustrating) is that these files work in Safari - but in Firefox, pressing the Submit button generates this error message:

> Error: sFeedback is not defined
>
> Source File: javascript:sFeedback(); Line: 1

Reading other postings like [JavaScript function not defined in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810399/javascript-function-not-defined-in-firefox), it seems that Firefox may need to have function defined before it can be called. If this is the case, is there a way - in my setup - to have function defined prior to call?

quiz.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 9.6" />
</head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="generateQuizItem.js">
</script>

<body onLoad="javascript:sGenerateQuizItem();">


</body>
</html>
```

And javascript:

```
var a0;
var a1;
var sum;
        
function sFeedback()
    {
    var answer = document.quiz_form.answer.value;
    document.write("answer = " + answer + "<br>");
    if (answer == sum)
        document.write("Right!<br>");
    else
        document.write("Wrong!<br>");
    }
    
function sGenerateQuizItem()
    {
    a0 = 20;
    a1 = 40;
    sum = a0 + a1;
    
    document.write("<form action=\"javascript:sFeedback();\" method=\"get\" name=\"quiz_form\">\n");
    document.write(a0 + " + " + a1 + " = ");
    document.write("<input name=\"answer\" id=\"answer\" type=\"text\" size=\"4\" maxlength=\"4\" /><br><br>\n");
    document.write("<button type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\">Submit</button>");
    document.write("</form>");
    }
```

Comment: Try putting the script reference within the head of your document.

Comment: Indeed, that should fix the issue.

Comment: Remove `language="JavaScript"` as well.

Comment: Lose the `javascript:` in your `onload`.

Comment: Thanks, all. Alas, changes have not made a difference to Firefox's error code. Good news, Safari continues to work.

Comment: Also, for the down voter: please provide solution. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the script reference within the head of your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <script src="generateQuizItem.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="sGenerateQuizItem();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see that this makes more sense - and should fix problem. Alas, it does not, so maybe something else is causing problem.

Comment: Wait a minute, your document.write statements are overwriting your initial page content and deleting the sFeedback() function. Why Safari is working I'm not sure of, but that's the core issue. Document.write is rarely useful, try using innerHTML to change the page content instead.

Comment: Thanks for solution and also for tutorial and intro to jsFiddle!

Comment: It works in Safari because Safari is buggy: it doesn't properly clear the global scope on `document.open`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've got some odd things going on.

document.write is a weird thing to use that behaves differently depending on WHEN you call it.  If it runs DURING THE PAGE LOAD then it will interject its output into the HTML...

```
<p>Hello your name is:
<script>
  document.write("Somebody");
</script>
</p>
```

However, if you use document.write **AFTER THE PAGE LOADS** then it will **REPLACE** the current page with the output of document.write.  Sometimes useful for debugging or dumping massive amounts of info -- not useful for anything else.

So, you usage of document.write **destroys** the current page as the code is running.  Different browsers will handle that differently.  Don't do it.

There are much better ways to modify the page.  Anything from include the form in the base HTML and hide it -- then display it later when you need it.

Use document.createElement and friends to build the data on the run.

As much as I dislike innerHTML, even *that* would be a better choice.

TL:DR
Long long ago, document.write was the only way to interact with the web pages.  Not been true in 20+ years or so.  Don't do it.  Pretend it doesn't exist.